# what is the difference between auto increment and sequence?

Tags: mysql

Is there any difference between auto increment ans sequence in mysql ?  i need a unique number all the time and once it gives it has to reserve the number until commit.

Comment: `sequence` = general purpose counter, of which there can be many in a db. auto_increment = a sequence-like counter, attached to a specific table, usually as its primary key, and there can only be one auto_inc value in any one mysql table.

Comment: so auto increment is a kind of sequence. there can be many sequences but there could be only one auto increment. I hope i understood it right

Comment: The InnoDB engine auto_increment will ensure the number is unique and reserved (regardless if you commit or not). http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-auto-increment-configurable.html

Comment: sequence has no special meaning in MyQSL. auto_increment does - as explained in the manual (although, confusingly, the General Index capitalizes the word)

Comment: only one auto_increment in a table. but obviously you can have multiple tables, and each table can have its own auto_increment. the auto_inc in each table is completely independent of every other auto_inc in other tables.